# Access Display two fields from one table

Tags: database, ms-access, field, lookup, data-integrity

I have an ASSET table with two fields one is the ASSET NAME, The other an ASSET SERIAL. The NAME always has a unique serial number. attached to it.

I have a MASTER LOG table, and the field for "ASSET" is a dropdown containing the ASSET NAMES. I have another field named "TAG"

Is there a way, that by selecting ASSET NAME, the TAG associated with the NAME from the ASSET table will populate?

Basically filling two fields from one lookup, if they are all unique entries.

Comment: is the tag the same as the serial ?

Comment: @BenMcIntyre yes that's exactly the case.

Comment: Normally, you'd only store the unique identifier in the second table, and look up the other info if you need it. The exception to that is logging information, where you may want to store the data in the state it was in at the time. It looks like this may be the case for you. In that case, no, there is no way of auto-populating the second field, but you often use an append query for these things and it's easy to add the extra field tot he query if you want to.